# LaTeX guide for MS Word users

Tags: msword, tutorials

I am a new Latex user but senior MS Word user. Where can I find guide and resources to migrate from MS Word to Latex for common formating and referencing features.

Formating in MS Word (and also Libre Office) is classified to character format, paragraph format and numbering format.

I want a guide shows me how to do same MS Word formating and referencing tasks in Latex by its order and classify in MS Word.

Comment: You could start with http://tug.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf but this is voor LaTeX2, not LaTeX3.

Comment: I think you can't "migrate" from Word to LaTeX. They're such a different things that's like asking how to migrate from, say, driving a bike to taking a train. The final effect is to change place, but the process, the idea, and the tool are so different they are completely disjointed. My advise is to start fresh with LaTeX for example at https://www.learnlatex.org and not trying to do parallels with Word.

Comment: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/134144) may also be interesting.

Comment: Latex3 is a programing interface (do `texdoc interface3` in your TeX install to bring up the documentation). For deeper programming, there is luatex/lualatex's lua (`texdoc luacode`). For general typesetting, the links in the other comments are good. The Latex Wikibook is quite comprehensive. Also, this site. Start with the topics and subject areas that interest you most (e.g., chemistry, linguistics, poetry) because there are many packages that extend latex (`fontspec`, `tikz`, `unicode-math`, `polyglossia`, `xparse`, `etoolbox`, `tcolorbox`...).

Comment: Try Lyx, which is a kind of gui for LaTeX.

Comment: Do not worry now for LaTeX 3 (it could be like Klingon for you).  Focus on basic LaTeX2, that is a macro language for semi-human beings  (it is not hard to understand what `\section{Introduction}` mean, for instance) and this  will be  the 99'9 % of what you really need. LyX is a good idea to be productive in little time and learn at the same time, if you pay attention to the code produced when you  use the GUI (there are a code pane preview). After some time, try to edit directly the code with a LaTeX editor with PDF preview, like TeXworks.

Answer (score 4):

I will distill the comments and my own thoughts into a hopefully coherent answer.

Microsoft Word and LaTeX are very different tools with very different design philosophies, and as @Rmano said in a comment one cannot really "migrate" from one to the other. If you are required to use a word processor or otherwise need one, you should use Word. If you want or need something beyond the capabilities of a word processor, then LaTeX may be a better solution. Converting between the two is technically possible, but frequently troublesome and, in my opinion, just not worth the effort. Use whichever one best meets your needs.

In most cases, the difference between the two is the separation of content from format. With word processors, one must always worry about both. One must frequently search for formatting commands and features in menus that are not always logically or efficiently designed. With LaTeX, a single document class takes care of formatting your document for you and all you need to be concerned with is the actual content. Of course once you become an experienced user, you can learn how to override default formatting but this is not always necessary. Again, it depends on your needs.

I suggest you begin by creating a free account at Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/) and look at their extensive set of templates and examples (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates). You can import any of these directly into your newly created account and start by reading through the source code and making small changes to see what happens each time you compile the document.

For newcomers, the best written tutorial may be The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e (http://tug.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) referenced by @Jesse op den Brouw in a comment above.

Another tool for beginners that did not exist until relatively recently, referenced by @Rmano above, is LearnLaTeX.org (https://www.learnlatex.org/)and upon further thought, this may be a better starting point for brand new beginners than Overleaf so consider starting there first.

Only after practicing with one of the suggest portals and reading The Not So Short Guide should even remotely consider installing a TeX/LaTeX distribution on your own computer, so do not even think about doing that just yet.

Comment: @Teepeemm I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

My simple recommendation

DIVE RIGHT IN -- DONT THINK

This website hosts thousands of questions and answers to get you going

In your nest question upload a typical MS Word doc which you would want formatted with `LateX` and request for a conversion

See the code used and experiment with it

!!Happy LateXing

Answer (score 0):

Please try `overleaf.com`. It's really nice and gives step by step guidelines for everything you may want to do as a beginner on LaTex.